# Having a problem calculating the compounded Interest

Tags: c++

I tried as I/P: 100, 10, 1 and it works fine so CI = 10 and total = 110
But with other example I can't get right answer can you please tell me what to do.

I tried to look at other questions here but I can't understand what the wrong I did.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<math.h>
 
using namespace std;
 
int main()
{
    float amount,rate,time_,total,compoundedInterest;
    cout<<"Amount: ";cin>>amount;
    cout<<"Rate of Interest: ";cin>>rate;
    cout<<"Time: ";cin>>time_;  
    compoundedInterest=amount*pow((rate/100),time_);    
    total=amount+compoundedInterest;
    cout<<"Compounded Interest: "<<compoundedInterest;    
    cout << endl; 
    cout<<"Total: "<<total;
    return 0;
}
```

Please Help me figure what is the problem.

Comment: https://www.calculatorsoup.com/calculators/financial/compound-interest-calculator.php At first blush, it just looks like your formula isn't correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Code:**

```
#include<iostream>
#include<math.h>
 
using namespace std;
 
int main()
{
    float amount,rate,time_,total,compoundedInterest;
    cout<<"Amount: ";cin>>amount;
    cout<<"Rate of Interest: ";cin>>rate;
    cout<<"Time: ";cin>>time_;  
    compoundedInterest=amount*pow((1+rate/100),time_)-amount;   
    total=amount+compoundedInterest;
    cout<<"Compounded Interest: "<<compoundedInterest;    
    cout << endl; 
    cout<<"Total: "<<total;
    return 0;
}
```

**Problem:**

The main problem with your CI rule it is wrong that is why you will find wrong O/P.
You can use this code which will works fine with you.

**Rules:**
[image]

**Note:**
I used the first rule to calculate CI here.

Resource:
[Link1](https://www.investor.gov/financial-tools-calculators/calculators/compound-interest-calculator)
[Link2](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/c/compoundinterest.asp#:%7E:text=Calculating%20Compound%20Interest-,Compound%20interest%20is%20calculated%20by%20multiplying%20the%20initial%20principal%20amount,subtracted%20from%20the%20resulting%20value.)

Comment: Please don't post images of text